# Get-Childitem Recursive but skip files in particular parent folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

This should be an easy question. I need to run `Get-Childitem`recursively to look for .jpgs in the following folder structure:

```
'D:\Images\' + $local:YM + '\' + $local:YMD + '\' + $env:USERNAME
```

The username folder contains jpgs and additional folders containing jpgs. I want the recursive `Get-Childitem` to address the jpgs in the subfolders of the username folder but skip the jpgs in the username folder itself.

For example I would like the `Get-Childitem` to address:

```
'D:\Images\2018_03\2018_03_19\Garrett\Shoes\Shoe.jpg'
```

but not:

```
'D:\Images\2018_03\2018_03_19\Garrett\Shoe.jpg'
```

I tried using the following path with no success:

```
'D:\Images\' + $local:YM + '\' + $local:YMD + '\' + $env:USERNAME + '\*\'
```

I'm not sure if that failed because I didn't state that the wildcard was a directory, if that's the case how do I do that? Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Exclude folder1,folder2` ?

Comment: So you think I could simply exclude the username folder? Will that not break the recursive sweep of the folders within the username folder?

Comment: @Hackerman your suggestion seems to work, go ahead and write it in as an answer and I will mark it as the answer when I've confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where-Object` to filter on the `DirectoryName` property:

```
$DirectoryNameToExclude = 'D:\Images\' + $local:YM + '\' + $local:YMD + '\' + $env:USERNAME
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -ne $DirectoryNameToExclude}
```

Comment: If he's using recursion, might as well use the `-Exclude` parameter for the pattern.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Problem with that is it would also exclude files with the matching name in subfolders

Comment: Ohhh. I see what he's trying to do now.  So he's trying to get files from folders in the username folder, but not the files in that username folder itself.

Comment: This is correct - I want to pull the jpgs from the various folders in the username folder, but not the jpgs in the username folder itself.